# import css file from node_modules

Tags: webpack, node-modules, css-loader

We have a private npm repository, where we have a css file as part of lib folder.

When trying to require that css file using

```
require('<module_name>/lib/abc.css')
```

and using webpack to load that, i am getting below error :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Any help, how to import such files

Comment: Your approach is correct, 'require' will force webpack to bundle this css.
Can you provide that css and show webpack config where you taking care about css?

Answer (score 0):

I have been stuck for days on this issue too (I am new to the node.js/Meteor/React/JavaScript world). I found a solution using webpackJS.

My working solution (applied to a tiny application that should make it easy to understand; I only display a datagrid using hard-coded data) is available on my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kevinrue/reactJS/tree/master/reactDataGrid) (commit 902c92c). The application is called "reactDataGrid", it is a subfolder of the repository, you just need to run "meteor" within that folder.

The two key steps in my case were:

- to create a **.babelrc** file with the content described [here](http://survivejs.com/webpack/advanced-techniques/configuring-react/) (and copied below). I believe this helps webpack parse the JSX syntax of react. I have a feeling this may be key to your issue as well, as it is reported as a `SyntaxError`.

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "es2015",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ],
    "react"
  ]
}
```

- the `require('react-datagrid/index.css')` statement inside my **main.jsx** file, that tells webpack to include that CSS file in the dependency tree of my app. This is actually an instruction described in the README of the zippyui/react-datagrid GitHub repository. (Unfortunately stackoverflow limits to two links in my post, so I cannot link it here anymore)

I cannot guarantee that this is the *preferred* method of doing it, but I can say that it works for me. I hope it helps.

Best,
Kevin